# Subscribe multiple channels with python websockets

Tags: python, websocket

The problem is to find a simple way to subscribe multiple channels using a single `websocket` in connection in `python`.

The problem is very simple and there are several solutions, however most of them use the `partial` function and we would like to avoid it.

Below is an example of a single subscription `subscribe_message_1` and we would also like to subscribe  `subscribe_message_2`. To simplify the problem, we present a real example using kraken.

```
import sys
import json
import signal
from websocket import create_connection

def alarmfunction(signalnumber, frame):
    signal.alarm(1)

def open_channel(ws, subscribe_message):
    try:
        ws.send(subscribe_message)
    except Exception as error:
        print("Feed subscription failed (%s)" % error)
        ws.close()
        sys.exit(1)

    while True:
        api_data = ws.recv()

        api_data = json.loads(api_data)

        print(type(api_data))
        print(api_data)


    ws.close()
    sys.exit(1)

signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, alarmfunction)

api_feed = "book"
api_symbol = "ETH/USD".upper() #sys.argv[1].upper()
api_symbol2 = "LTC/USD".upper() #sys.argv[1].upper()
api_depth = 10 #sys.argv[2]
api_domain = "wss://ws.kraken.com/"
api_book = {"bid":{}, "ask":{}}

try:
    ws = create_connection(api_domain)
except Exception as error:
    print("WebSocket connection failed (%s)" % error)
    sys.exit(1)

subscribe_message_1 = '{"event":"subscribe", "subscription":{"name":"%(feed)s", "depth":%(depth)s}, "pair":["%(symbol)s"]}' % {"feed":api_feed, "depth":api_depth, "symbol":api_symbol}
subscribe_message_2 = '{"event":"subscribe", "subscription":{"name":"%(feed)s", "depth":%(depth)s}, "pair":["%(symbol)s"]}' % {"feed":api_feed, "depth":api_depth, "symbol":api_symbol2}

open_channel(ws, subscribe_message_1)
```

Answer (score 1):

We just have to evoque the send twice, like demonstrate bellow:

```
def open_channel(ws, subscribe_message, subscribe_message1):
    try:
        ws.send(subscribe_message)
        ws.send(subscribe_message1)
    except Exception as error:
        print("Feed subscription failed (%s)" % error)
        ws.close()
        sys.exit(1)

    while True:
        api_data = ws.recv()

        api_data = json.loads(api_data)

        print(type(api_data))
        print(api_data)


    ws.close()
    sys.exit(1)

open_channel(ws, subscribe_message_1, subscribe_message_2)
```